# Cannot save changes to profile, even though I didn't change my display name

Tags: support, profile-page, display-names

When I edit my profile and save, it gives me this error:

> Oops! There was a problem updating your profile:
>   Display name may only be changed once every 30 days; you may change again in 6 days

I did **not** change the display name. In fact, I tried several times where I did not change anything or only changed 1 field.

Same thing on IE 11 and Chrome

Comment: I took a look - you did change the display name - at the same day you registered, less than 30 days ago.

Comment: @Oded Yes but i am trying to change my profile and not display name but I cannot because I get that display name error. I should be able to change my profile. I just want to add a profile description and an image.

Comment: Strange - looks like your previous display name is coming up in the form - if you change it to the current one you should be able to save. I'll have to look at why that happened.

Comment: I don't recall ever changing display name to be honest. What is the current one vs the previous one?

Comment: Previous one ends with a `B`, current one with a `b`.

Comment: Thank you, changing to the current one worked. Good luck finding out what caused the problem. Let me know if I can help you in any way.

Comment: Caching, I bet...