# Updating Profile Picture/Profile Bug?

Tags: bug, profile-page

Trying to upload a profile picture here for my profile on Stack Overflow, and keep getting the error message:

> Oops! There was a problem updating your profile: Display name may only be changed once every 30 days; you may change again in 10 days.

Problem is I'm not editing my display name (or any other settings), just trying to upload a picture and save settings, can't seem to get past the error message.

Any ideas?

Comment: [This guy recently had the same problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316900/cannot-save-changes-to-profile-even-though-i-didnt-change-my-display-name). Turns out that his *old* user name was being pre-filled in the form, so when he was trying to save it, it failed because the system thought he was trying to change his name. Make sure that "Robert" is filled in in the user name box before trying to submit. (Doesn't make it any less of a bug, though. Oded was supposed to look into it.)